# Matching strings not ending with .html

Tags: regex, iis, regex-lookarounds, url-rewrite-module

I want to redirect my website users when they hit a REST path without the trailing slash.

*Example.*

```
http://mywebsite.my/it/products/brand/name => http://mywebsite.my/it/products/brand/name/
http://mywebsite.my/it/products => http://mywebsite.my/it/products/
http://mywebsite.my => http://mywebsite.my/

http://mywebsite.my/it/products/brand/name/code.html => ???
```

Well, I don't want the last one to be rewritten, I don't want the trailing slash when the URL ends with *.html*.

I'm working with URL rewrite module of IIS7, and this is my "slash-rule".

```
<rule name="SLASHFINALE" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*[^/])$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}/" />
</rule>
```

In other words, if the input url matches that regex (everything **not** ending with a slash), I rewrite the same URL adding the trailing slash.

So my rule would be the same, but with that little addition: rewrite all URLs, except the ones (already) having the trailing slash or the ones ending with **".html"**.

I wrote this

```
(.*(?<!html)[^\/])$
```

but I can't understand why it's not working.

Comment: Your lookbehind (if supported), is not at the good place, put it at the end of the pattern and add the dot (escaped) to avoid confusion with for example `phtml`

Comment: (.*[^/](?<!html))$  this works, but not in actual IIS7! Is that lookbehind supported?

Comment: In this case, use a lookahead instead, but like that: `(?!.*\.html$).*[^/]$`

Comment: I'm trying that, indeed it works but it is always matching: (when I have .html the capturing group is always html)

Comment: `(?!.*\.html$)(.*[^/])$` I haven't written the capture group.

Comment: Ok sorry, I didn't explain myself. Your regex works perfectly. http://mywebsite.my/it/products/brand/name/code.htm matches all and that's ok, http://mywebsite.my/it/products/brand/name/code.html matches "html", in that last case I don't want my pattern to match at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS Javascript-flavored regex parser does not support conditional expressions.

I ended up with this:

```
<match url="(.*[^\.]...[^\/]$)" />
```

Enough for me.