# REGEX on IIS server - redirect trailing slash

Tags: regex, iis

Is there a Regex guru in here ?

I tried to find the answer, I got close on that one :
[Matching strings not ending with .html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27427826/matching-strings-not-ending-with-html)
but unfortunately, it doesn't fulfill my need :

**On IIS 7.5 want to redirect any address without trailing slash :**

- *catalog*
- *catalog/chapter*

to

- *catalog/chapter/*

**but not**

- *catalog/*
- *catalog/chapter/*
- *catalog/chapter/anything.any*
- *catalog/chapter/anything.any4*
- *catalog/chapter/anything.an*

(extension between 2 and 4 char)

**Tricky part is**, I need to get that first group "catalog" as it's used in the conditions to check if it exists in rewrite tables.
For now, I'm getting that first group with : ((.+?)(?=/|$))

But then, to check the following (if there's any), I'm stuck.

I can't figure how to do it...

Thanks a bunch for your help !!!

***EDIT :***

To be clearer, this is what I'm looking to achieve :

- *catalog*                     ==> MATCH + captures "catalog" in group 1
- *catalog/chapter*             ==> MATCH + captures "catalog" in group 1
- *catalog/*                      ==> NO MATCH
- *catalog/chapter/*              ==> NO MATCH
- *catalog/chapter/anything.any*  ==> NO MATCH
- *catalog/chapter/anything.any4* ==> NO MATCH
- *catalog/chapter/anything.an*   ==> NO MATCH

Comment: Try `^(?!catalog\/chapter/.*$).*[^/]$`

Answer (score 1):

You can transform your conditions into **negative lookaheads**:

```
^([^/]+)(?!.*\.\w+$)(?!.*/$).*$
        ^---- 1----^^-- 2--^
```

See [a regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kF6cS9/3)

The first one will fail the match when the URL ends with a file extension (`\w+$` will require 1 or more word characters to appear at the end of the string).
The second lookahead will fail the match if the URL ends with a `/`.

**Note**: escaping `/` might not be necessary in your environment if you are not using regex delimiters.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, Thanks for your help,
Unfortunately this is not exactly what I want.
I want to 
 1 - capture the catalog name either anything in the URL, without trailing slash as http://example.com/catalog or anything before the first slash as in http://example.com/catalog/anything/behind 
 2 - If there's anything after /catalog, then I want to check whether it's a file or not. If it's not, and has no trailing slash, then redirect

Comment: Please check `^([^/]+)(?!.*\.[^.]+$).*[^/]$`

Comment: close, but it still matches : 

`catalog/test/index.html`

whereas I don't want to as the URL is correct that way, and doesn't need to be redirected.

Comment: The [`^([^/]+)(?!.*\.[^.]+$).*[^/]$`](https://regex101.com/r/sU0aV5/2) can match `catalog/test/index.html`. It ends with an extension and cannot be matched with the regex. Also, I think the lookahead should be a bit precised like `^([^/]+)(?!.*\.[^/.]+$).*[^/]$`.

Comment: I finally found it ! 

`^([^/]+)(?!.*\.\w{1,4}$)(?!.*\/$).*$`

Thanks for your help, Wiktor !

Comment: With that one, you limit to extensions from 1 to 4 characters. I updated the answer. The only difference between `^([^/]+)(?!.*\.\w+$)(?!.*/$).*$` and `^([^/]+)(?!.*\.[^/.]+$).*[^/]$` is that the latter requires at least one character to be in the URL after the first capture group. You have not provided a test case for that scenario, so I was not paying attention to that aspect.

Comment: I shortened the answer to include the relevant details only. Please consider accepting/upvoting if it worked/turned out helpful to you.